# how to detect a search button while an alert is shown in an android

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

Hi stackoverflow friends

I recently faced an issue that how can i disable global search button in android while an alert is shown in the screen.I don't want to disappear the alert box by using search button. I need to user must click the alertbox button and disappears in that way.So I want to disable the search button while alert box is shown. But I can disable the back button using setCancable(false).How can I solve this ?

THanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Could you provide a better question because I'm completely clueless..

Comment: HI androider im my app when an alert box is show, I don't want to remove the alert box to be removed by using search button. So i need to disable the search button while alert box is shown.

Comment: Your question, along with the comment, is really confusing :-/

Comment: Hi sheikh Aman I edit my question. Hope now u got it

Comment: I think using `setCancable(false)` is the right way to go even if it does not disable the global search button. Simply because this is the regular behaviour of the system in case of non-cancellable alert.

Comment: Hi shlublu setCancable(false) is only for disable back button but not for search button. How can i disable search button?

Answer (score 0):

So, Your intention is to provide non-cancelable alert.
Suggesting to set `OnDismissListener` and just show alert again. It's not very good from visual perspective (alert get closed and opened again).
Below is some obvious example how to achieve such non-cancelable alert (code is inside Acctivity class):

```
/** reference to our alert */
private AlertDialog alert = null;
/** to indicate if alert dismissed by key */
private boolean alertKeyPressed = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    // Say, we need to show alert when activity resumed

    if(true/*provide condition to show alert*/) {

        showAlert();
    }
}

/**
 * Show non dismissable alert
 */
private void showAlert() {
    if(null == this.alert) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.str_alert_title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.str_alert_text);
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

        builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                YourActivity.this.alertKeyPressed = true;

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        this.alert = builder.create();

        this.alert.setOwnerActivity(this);
        this.alert.show();

        this.alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {


                // dialog is not allowed to be dismissed, so show it again
                YourActivity.this.alert = null;

                if(!YourActivity.this.alertKeyPressed) {
                    showAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, I don't think it's the right way to left such alert for the user, sometimes it might be needed for cases like evaluation restriction etc.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onSearchRequested` in your Activity and have it return `false` while the dialog is being shown. This should block the request, as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29):

> You can override this function to force global search, e.g. in
>   response to a dedicated search key, or to block search entirely (by
>   simply returning false).
>
> Returns true if search launched, and false if activity blocks it. The
>   default implementation always returns true.

Answer (score 0):

```
.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener()
{   
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        //There you catch the key, do whatever you want to do.
        //Return true if you handled the key event, so nothing will trigger.
        //Return false if you want your activity to handle.
        return true;
    }
})
```

Just add the code above to alert dialog builder. Hope this snippet would help. Good luck.